# Platform specific RowHeight not working in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm defining a list view as follows:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEngine, Mode=TwoWay}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.RowHeight>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">
            <On Platform="Android">52</On>
            <On Platform="UWP">154</On>
        </OnPlatform>
         </ListView.RowHeight>
</ListView>
```

But I get an error message saying:

No property, bindable property, or event found for 'RowHeight', or mismatching type between value and property.

And if I drop the  out it compiles. Does anyone know how I can fix the issue?

Comment: I am on VS for Mac v7.4.1 and XF v2.5.0.121934 your code is compiling with enabled XAMLC and working as expected. What is your setup?

Comment: My setup is Visual Studio 17 on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on VS for Mac v7.4.1 and XF v2.5.0.121934 your code is compiling with enabled XAMLC and working as expected. What is your setup?

Try to update to latest and greatest version of Xamarin.Forms.